# Display custom post types in dropdown with option "all"

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

`wp_dropdown_categories()` function has an argument `show_option_all` to search in all terms if selected. I need something similar in my custom post type select:

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">   
    <div class="select-wrap">
        <label>Select location</label>

        <?php 
        $args = array(
            'show_option_all' => 'All locations',
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'echo' => 1,
            'value_field' => 'slug',
        );

        $args['taxonomy'] = 'location';
        $args['class'] = 'select--field';

        wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); 
        ?>

    </div>

    <div class="select-wrap">
        <label>Select service</label>

        <select class="select--field">

            <?php
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'service',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        </select> 
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="location">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="service">

    <button type="submit" class="search-btn btn--lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty option in first position:

```
...
echo '<option value="">All locations</option>';
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
endwhile;
...
```

Comment: Thank You, is this really working?

Comment: It works. You can also check the html generatad by wp_dropdown_categories( $args ) for your first exaple. And there should be <option value="">All locations</option>.